# My discord bot does replies to certain messages but not the other

Tags: python, automation, discord, bots

I am making a discord bot that I can send the day and lesson number then it prints out the lesson.
I am planning on making it reply with simple if statements. It replies to some of the if statements but not the rest.

```
import discord
import discord.client
import random

TOKEN = *************************************************

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower().startswith("hello"):
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello, {message.author.display_name}!')
        return

    elif message.content.lower().startswith("S1"):
        await message.channel.send(f'Arabic')
        return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

1. Am I going the right way about creating the bot?
2. If not, what and how should I go about creating it?
3. What has gone wrong?
4. How do I fix it?
   [Messages Replied and aired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fBZb.png)

Comment: First thing first delete that `TOKEN` and never share it again on the internet. You have no handling for the messages other than `hello` and `s1`

Comment: @TheOdinBorson you should regenerate your token asap because the moment you post it here on SO, the token is still visible in the revision history and may have already been scraped. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335058/what-happens-if-we-post-something-confidential)

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok. You can read the following article and see if you missed something.

[How to Make a Discord Bot in Python](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/)